# AsyncController to process a quantity of requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The authentication in my web application works like SO. When user logs on, a background request is started to a 3rd website to get the user's information. Something like this:

```
public AccountController : AsyncController
{
    public void LogonAsync()
    {
        using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadDataCompleted += (sender, args) =>
            {
                //do something
                AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
            };

            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
            client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(theUrlToValidate));
        }        
    }

    public ActionResult LogonCompleted()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

It looks correct. But when the web application goes online, I can see from performance monitor, the requests queued is growing larger and larger, then the application pool is down. I modified the action, to return constant string:

```
public ActionResult Logon()
{
    return Content("hello");
}
```

But still it can't prevent the application crushing from growing requests. Now I want to know: (1) Is my async controller implemented correctly? The crashing is not because of the wrong code, but the quantity of requests, right? (2) How to improve the performance when lots of requests comes? Currently I have two web servers with WIN SERVER 2003, the web application is built on MongoDB/ASP.NET MVC 3. Maybe the developers working for SO can tell me how SO handle this issue.

Comment: In the example you posted, `AccountController` doesn't derive from anything. I guess it's a typo. Also when you say that `return Content("hello");` is also problematic, well, it's hard to believe. A controller action like this one could handle many requests. And when I say many, I mean **MANY**. So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Yes it's a typo, I edited the post. Thanks for your prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but could you be having a problem because you are disposing the webclient instance before the download is actually done? I think the code to .Dispose web client should be moved into the download complete handler, or just ignoring it completely as it will be cleaned up by garbage collection.